# Spring boot JWT auth

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, authentication, spring-boot

i try to develop web app using spring boot , for authentication i m using following tutorial : http://www.techforumist.com/spring-boot-security-jpa-using-jwt-angularjs-tutorial-2/#comment-2848

its works nice but after refresh page connection Loss(Log out) - and need re login .
i know i need session / cookies but i don't know how to do this .

can you Help me  ? 
here is source code : https://github.com/techforumist/jwt-spring-boot-security-angularjs

thnx

Answer (score 1):

You don't need session/cookies, because you use JWT token, which contains information about the user.
In source code, I can't see any code to store jwt token in browser. I can't see any refresh jwt as well. So I guess, you have to implement that (or at least token store).
This is how I see it:

1. Store JWT token in browser memory. In
   https://github.com/techforumist/jwt-spring-boot-security-angularjs/blob/master/src/main/resources/static/app/controllers/login.js you
   have `res.token` value. You can save this value to browser local
   storage with `localStorage.setItem("JwtToken", res.token)`.
2. Authenticate user after refresh in your frontend app.
   To do this, you have to grab the token from local storage when app is loading, set it as default header to all http requests and make request to `/user` endpoint in your backend, to get User object. You can encode user from token (with base64), but calling endpoint will be simpler.
   So on angular you can use run method (it's done before initialization):

   `angular.module('fooApp').run(['$http', '$rootScope', 'AuthService',
     function($http, $rootScope, AuthService) {
        var token = localStorage.getItem("JwtToken");
        if(token) {
          $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
          $http.get('./user').then(function(resp){
            AuthService.user = resp;
          });
        }
     }
   ]);`

This should do what the trick and user will be logged after page refresh.
Of course the next step should be jwt token refresh (on run/route change/every request - there are many options), but that is beyond the question.

Comment: hi, wkubasik , thnx for answer , 
step 1. done Successfully, (i Check it with console command localstorage and its Returns token ..)
Step 2 . i m add this code under  home.js 
angular.module('JWTDemoApp').run( >>>your code<<])
// Creating the Angular Controller
.controller('HomeController', function($http, $scope, AuthService) {
 $scope.user = AuthService.user;
});
but i have 401 
error
:
"Unauthorized"message:"
Invalid Authorization header."
path:"/user"
status:401

can you help me to resolved problem ?

Comment: Hi. I did little mistake in code. Can you cut the line `$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;` and paste it before the `$http.get('./user')` request call? Because we should set jwt token to header before this request. I updated my answer. Hope it helps

Comment: i do this but after reload nothing change still log out : (

Comment: If you use Chrome browser, click f12, go to "Network" tab, and look for /user request (you have to refresh the page before it shows there). Then click on this request and choose "Preview" tab. You should see your user object there. Check if user is there. You can add ResponseEntity<AppUser> as return value on your backend in /user endpoint.

Comment: {"id":1,"name":"admin","username":"admin","roles":["USER","ADMIN"]}
i see this object but dont understand next step "You can add ResponseEntity<AppUser> as return value on your backend in /user endpoint."

Comment: nevermid, user is in response. So, you should debug and check, what happens after /user request. You can add brakepoint in chrome and debug javascript code. Look whats in AuthService.user, after `AuthService.user = resp;`. And look what is in $scope.user, after HomeController is loaded. there should be user object.

Comment: (WEB_PAGE context) Lazy require of app.binding did not set the binding field
i have this error

Comment: after going controller i have its breaked . and throws error : (WEB_PAGE context) Lazy require of app.binding did not set the binding field

Comment: Did you install some dev plugin in browser? It looks like browser problem, not application error.

Comment: yes i disabled this but still not going in controler , i men its going 
controller .controller('HomeController', function($http, $scope, AuthService) {  <-- hear brakepoint stops
 $scope.user = AuthService.user;  <-- not goes here 
});

Comment: PageNotFoundController  - its goes in this controller

Comment: and what will happen when you go to http://localhost:8080/#/home ?? I can't help without seeing your code. Maybe something is messed up with ui-router configuration.

Comment: .state('home', {
  parent : 'nav',
  url : '/',
  views : {
   'content@' : {
    templateUrl : 'app/views/home.html',
    controller : 'HomeController'
   }
  }
here my route cfg ,  localhost:8080/#/home ?? - no , just localhost:8080/#

Comment: 1) what happens when you go to localhost:8080/#/home ? 
2) delete/comment all code we added, and check if it still redirects to page_not_found.   
It's hard to tell, I can't help without source code

Comment: https://github.com/ZuraTikaradze/Spring-Boot-Security/blob/master/sourcecode/src/main/resources/static/app/controllers/home.js

i do this  look i think its right code no ? but no result